# How do you effectively use pd.DataFrame.apply on rows with duplicate values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, apply

The function that I'm applying is a little expensive, as such I want it to only calculate the value once for unique values.

The only solution I've been able to come up with has been as follows:

This step because apply doesn't work on arrays, so I have to convert the unique values into a series.

```
new_vals = pd.Series(data['column'].unique()).apply(function)
```

This one because .merge has to be used on dataframes.

```
new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame( index = data['column'].unique(), data = new_vals.values)
```

Finally Merging The results

```
yet_another= pd.merge(data, new_dataframe, right_index = True, left_on = column)
data['calculated_column'] = yet_another[0]
```

So basically I had to Convert my values to a Series, apply the function, convert to a Dataframe, merge the results and use that column to create me new column.

I'm wondering if there is some one-line solution that isn't as messy. Something pythonic that doesn't involve re-casting object types multiple times. I've tried grouping by but I just can't figure out how to do it.

My best guess would have been to do something along these lines

```
data[calculated_column] = dataframe.groupby(column).index.apply(function)
```

but that isn't right either.

This is an operation that I do often enough to want to learn a better way to do, but not often enough that I can easily find the last time I used it, so I end up re-figuring a bunch of things again and again.

If there is no good solution I guess I could just add this function to my library of common tools that I hedonistically > from me_tools import *

```
def apply_unique(data, column, function):
    new_vals = pd.Series(data[column].unique()).apply(function)
    new_dataframe = pd.DataFrame( data = new_vals.values, index =         
    data[column].unique() )
    result = pd.merge(data, new_dataframe, right_index = True, left_on = column)
    return result[0]
```

Comment: My guess is you can call `groupby` + `transform`.

Comment: `data.groupby('column', as_index=False)['column'].transform(function)`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the transform option doesn't work if the type of data['column'] is a string 


`TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types`

Comment: If the calculations are expensive, and you are already going to use `.apply` (so it's as slow as a for-loop), you should consider memoizing your function.

Comment: please, sample data and an example function!

Comment: along the lines of what @juanpa.arrivillaga is suggesting (memoizing), I'd do something like: (1) run function on unique values and store that as a dict or series, and then (2) `df['x'].map(series)`.  I'd expect that to be faster than what you are doing in some cases (but not others).  Just depends on the data and function.

Comment: For anyone reading this: I would like to add a note here just to say that the .apply as juanpa suggests is NOT as slow as a for loop. It is orders of magnitude faster.

Comment: Did you find  solution for your problem?  Could you please share your findings?  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like this:

```
def apply_unique(df, orig_col, new_col, func):
    return df.merge(df[[orig_col]]
                    .drop_duplicates()
                    .assign(**{new_col: lambda x: x[orig_col].apply(func)}
                           ), how='inner', on=orig_col)
```

This will return the same DataFrame as performing:

```
df[new_col] = df[orig_col].apply(func)
```

but will be much more performant when there are many duplicates.

**How it works:**

We join the original DataFrame (calling) to another DataFrame (passed) that contains two columns; the original column and the new column transformed from the original column.

The new column in the passed DataFrame is assigned using `.assign` and a lambda function, making it possible to apply the function to the DataFrame that has already had `.drop_duplicates()` performed on it.

A `dict` is used here for convenience only, as it allows a column name to be passed in as a `str`.

**Edit:**
As an aside: best to drop `new_col` if it already exists, otherwise the `merge` will append suffixes to each `new_col`

```
if new_col in df:
    df = df.drop(new_col, axis='columns')
```